# How to search by Last Name in a Full name in SQL?

Tags: sql

I have the following data.

```
FullName
---------------
Ray,John
Daly,Raymond
```

I want to make a search using last name.

I tried this

```
SELECT FullName 
FROM Names 
WHERE UPPER(FullName) LIKE UPPER('%ray%')
```

This returns both the rows as there is a clear match.

However searching by first name was easier. I just used the following query

```
SELECT FullName 
FROM Names  
WHERE UPPER(FullName) LIKE UPPER(', %ray%')
```

I am not sure how to accomplish this. Should I split the full name as comma delimited values and ignore the first name. Please help.

Comment: You should store the first and last name in seperate columns.

Comment: But, dont have that privilege now. The table is all set. :(

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle? There might be DBMS specific solutions for this that work better than a simple `like` search.

Comment: You could always alter the table and run a query to update a newly added field with the corresponding text from the original column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

assuming the last name is the bit before the comma:
and you want lastnames containing the subscting 'ray'

```
 SELECT FullName FROM Names WHERE UPPER(FullName) LIKE UPPER('%ray%,%')
```

if you want last name exactly 'ray' use

```
 SELECT FullName FROM Names WHERE UPPER(FullName) LIKE UPPER('ray,%')
```

if your database has ILIKE  using that may help performance depending on which indices you have

```
 SELECT FullName FROM Names WHERE FullName ILIKE 'ray,%';
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted. Though I was a bit bad at articulating my exact scenario. Thanks a ton Jasen.

Answer (score 1):

```
     SELECT FullName FROM Names
      WHERE UPPER(FullName) LIKE
      UPPER('%ray%,%')
```

Just add the comma after the expression!

Comment: that only matches names starting with a space abd ending with a comma

Comment: @jasen made a typing mistake.Edited!

Comment: `'%ray%,'` still requires the name column end with a comma.

Comment: @jasen thnks . almost forgot that !

Answer (score 0):

Just take out one percentage mark, as such:

```
SELECT FullName FROM Names WHERE UPPER(FullName) LIKE UPPER('ray%')
```

percentage marks on both sides searches entire string.

percentage mark only on the right searches the beginning of the string onwards.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of searching for `ray` why not search for `ray,`?

Does this achieve what you are after?

Comment: @dane it would solve the problem only for lastnames ending with ray. Other lastnames that dont end with ray but contain ray will not get printed

Comment: I see what you mean. This will not work properly if he has other last names that end with ray

Comment: Searching for names by substring seems like an usual need, in the example `ray,%` would find the wanted row and reject the unwanted row.